# Replacing all characters of a given string with a specific single character

Tags: java, string

I need to replace all characters of a String with a single character. For example,

A string like `ABCDEF` is given. The replacement operation should produce the output like `######`. All six characters in the given string should be replaced by a fixed, single character `#`as for an example.

---

One ugly way of doing this is to use the `replaceAll()` method in a way as shown below.

```
System.out.println("ABCDEF".replaceAll(".", "#"));
```

This would produce the output `######` as expected but I think, it is not a recommended way. (It does issue a warning).

---

Another way is to use the `Arrays.fill()` method as follows.

```
char[]c={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
Arrays.fill(c, '#');

System.out.println(c);
```

But this requires a character array and I don't need a character array.

---

Is there a precise/recommended way to achieve this (may be available in an external library)?

The String and the replacement character can be any valid String and character respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache commons [`StringUtils repeat()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) have such

```
StringUtils.repeat(yourChar, requiredSize);
```

Ex:

```
 StringUtils.repeat("a", 3)  = "aaa"
```

The above method is available for `char` type also.

Comment: After approximately two months the question has been asked, it is safe to assume that this is the final answer. Thanks.